# Magento inner pages 404 Not Found but homepage getting with nginx server

Tags: php, magento, nginx, plesk, hhvm

This is my host file:

```
server {
  root     /path/to/root/domain/html;
  index    index.php;
  server_name servername.de;
  location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires 30d;
  }
  location ^~ /(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }
  location /var/export/ { internal; }
  location /. { return 404; }
  location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }
  location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
  location ~* .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include fastcgi_params;
 }
}
```

I have changed "Use Web Server Rewrites" to "Yes" from Magento Admin panel to make the Urls SEO friendly(without index.php). And i have cleared the magento cache from admin panel after restarting the nginx.
Can anyone help me to find out that the nginx configured correctly or why am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself fixed the issue. I was using Plesk and there was an option to add Additional nginx directives. I removed the host file “/etc/nginx/conf.d/DOMAIN.conf”(Individual sites section in https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento. Remember to configure  “/etc/nginx/nginx.conf” properly.) and added the below code in my "Additional nginx directives" admin area in Plesk.

```
location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires 30d;
}

location /. {
    return 404;
}

location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php;
}

location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

location ~ .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite / /index.php last;
    }
    fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this configuration:

```
server {
    root     /path/to/root/domain/html;
    index    index.php;
    server_name servername.de;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }
    location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }
    location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
    location ~* .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } 

        expires off;

        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; 
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    }

    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
       deny all;
       access_log off;
       log_not_found off;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
       log_not_found off;
       access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
       allow all;
       log_not_found off;
       access_log off;
    }
}
```

Also, for this and related issues, you may check the official Magento guides: https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento

Answer (score 2):

This line made ​​a difference for me.

```
location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
```